# Weighted sum of product of binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, multinomial-theorem

I am trying to evaluate the sum

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k} \binom{N-n}{k}x^k$,

Here $x$ is some positive real

My approach so far has been to first to compute the summation $\displaystyle  \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{N-n}{k}x^k$ , then on differentiating with respect to x, we can find the inner summation in my original expression.

I am however not able to find a clean expression for this, though it looks quite structures. I was able to use the Vandermonde inequality to show that $\displaystyle  \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{N-n}{k} = \binom{N}{n}$, but was not able to get the $x^k$ into the summation.

Another approach I tried was to consider the constant term (in $x$) in $\displaystyle (1+x)^n\bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{x}\bigg)^{N-n}$ , but was unable to obtain anything from this line.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Edit: If $k<N-n$, then $\displaystyle \binom{N-n}{k}=0$.

Comment: Maybe reverse the summation?

Comment: I tried it. Ran into a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hoping that you enjoy hypergeometric functions.*

$$f_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k\,\binom{n}{k}\, \binom{N-n}{k}\,x^k=n x (N-n) \, _2F_1(1-n,n-N+1;2;x)$$ where appears  the [Gaussian or ordinary hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). This was "simple".

Now, being stuck, using a CAS for a few values of $N$ (since the CAS also was stuck for the general case), it seems that there are two patterns depending on the parity of $N$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 N & \sum_{n=1}^N f_n \\
 2 & x \\
 4 & 2 x^2+10 x \\
 6 & 3 x^3+42 x^2+35 x \\
 8 & 4 x^4+108 x^3+252 x^2+84 x \\
 10 & 5 x^5+220 x^4+990 x^3+924 x^2+165 x \\
 12 & 6 x^6+390 x^5+2860 x^4+5148 x^3+2574 x^2+286 x \\
 14 & 7 x^7+630 x^6+6825 x^5+20020 x^4+19305 x^3+6006 x^2+455 x \\
 16 & 8 x^8+952 x^7+14280 x^6+61880 x^5+97240 x^4+58344 x^3+12376 x^2+680 x 
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 x \\
 5 & 12 x^2+20 x \\
 7 & 24 x^3+112 x^2+56 x \\
 9 & 40 x^4+360 x^3+504 x^2+120 x \\
 11 & 60 x^5+880 x^4+2376 x^3+1584 x^2+220 x \\
 13 & 84 x^6+1820 x^5+8008 x^4+10296 x^3+4004 x^2+364 x \\
 15 & 112 x^7+3360 x^6+21840 x^5+45760 x^4+34320 x^3+8736 x^2+560 x \\
 17 & 144 x^8+5712 x^7+51408 x^6+159120 x^5+194480 x^4+95472 x^3+17136 x^2+816 x 
\end{array}
\right)$$ and the coefficients seem to be corresponding to "simple" polynomials in $N$ (some of the sequences were found in $OEIS$).

Answer (score 0):

I'll try Sharky's suggestion.

$\begin{array}\\
s( N)
&=\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k} \binom{N-n}{k}x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{n=k}^N  k\binom{n}{k} \binom{N-n}{k}x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^N kx^k\sum_{n=k}^N  \binom{n}{k} \binom{N-n}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^N kx^k\sum_{n=k}^N  \dfrac{n!(N-n)!}{k!(n-k)!k!(N-n-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac{kx^k}{k!^2}\sum_{n=k}^N  \dfrac{n!(N-n)!}{(n-k)!(N-n-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac{kx^k}{k!^2}\sum_{n=0}^{N-k}  \dfrac{(n+k)!(N-n-k)!}{(n)!(N-n-2k)!}\\
\end{array}
$

And I don't see where to go from here.

So I'll leave this in the hope
that someone else
might find it useful.